# Report IDs with linked table field not containing known text

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2013

I'm attempting to create a Crystal Report which will report on "jobs" which don't have a "document" with a given phrase in the title.

The relevant tables have the following structure:

```
Job             Doc_Job             Doc_VO
l_job_id    ->  l_job_id            s_name
                l_doc_job_id    ->  l_doc_job_id
```

Where "Job" is a unique file (one per client), but there are multiple documents for each job (each contained within a "Doc_VO" table). For instance, we may have a documents for a client named:

- Variation 1
- Variation 2
- Outstanding Variation 3
- Variation 4
- Outstanding Variation 5
- Other Variation 6

I'd like to list all jobs which have a document without "Outstanding" in the title.

I know how to include/exclude all unique documents with "Outstanding" in their title (variations of the below), but can't figure out how to make it so that only unique "Jobs" which have linked documents meeting my criteria are shown.

```
not({Doc_VO.s_name} like "*Outstanding*")
```

Using the above line can be used to produce a report like:

```
JOB         DOCUMENT                    OTHER INFO
Job 1       Variation 2                 .....
Job 1       Other Variation 4           .....
Job 2       Variation 1                 .....
Job 2       Misc Variation 2            .....
Job 2       Variation 6                 .....
Job 3       Other Variation 3           .....
```

Whereas I'm after:

```
JOB         OTHER INFO
Job 1       .....
Job 2       .....
Job 3       .....
```

Sorry if the above is unclear, I've only been working with Crystal & SQL for a few months. Please let me know if anything needs clarification or further explanation. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are getting multiple rows based on the Document column. If you do not need that in your results try removing the column.